# Applying different style sheets dynamically into a layout

Tags: jquery, css

I have a layout in which i have to apply different extrenal stylesheets based on the condition selected in the home page.Condition is i have to select a user from the dropdown in the home page, based on the user selected in the home page I have to dynamically load extrenal css files and apply it to the layout.I am using Jquery. How can i do this in jquery.

Comment: I didn't get why my question was  down voted?I didn't get any kind of answer any where on the web so that i posted here.Please remove those down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourSelectId").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "something") {
            //load css
            var styleUrl = "some_stylesheet_url.css";
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+styleUrl+'" >')
            .appendTo("head");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yep.this is what exactly i am looking for.I tried it and it's working.Thanks alot